# Передача данных из php в json через ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Добрый вечер, подскажите пожалуйста как в js (можно с использованием jQuery) через ajax передать данные массива структуры из php файла в json формате и поместить эти данные в таблицу?

В условии при loadTasks должны выгружаться все данные из php, там будет предусмотрена еще сортировка, но пока хотелось бы понять как просто получить данные можно какой-то пример?

index.html

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name:</th>
            <th>Type:</th>
            <th>Date:</th>
            <th>Status:</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

func.php

```
<?php
$tasks = [
    [
        'id' => '4',
        'name' => 'Task 4',
        'type' => 'frontend',
        'date' => '1512403290',
        'status' => '0',
    ],
    [
        'id' => '5',
        'name' => 'Task 5',
        'type' => 'frontend',
        'date' => '1512403320',
        'status' => '0',
    ],
    [
        'id' => '6',
        'name' => 'Task 6',
        'type' => 'backend',
        'date' => '1512403350',
        'status' => '1',
    ],
    [
        'id' => '2',
        'name' => 'Task 2',
        'type' => 'frontend',
        'date' => '1512403200',
        'status' => '0',
    ],
    [
        'id' => '3',
        'name' => 'Task 3',
        'type' => 'frontend',
        'date' => '1512403230',
        'status' => '0',
    ],
    [
        'id' => '1',
        'name' => 'Task 1',
        'type' => 'backend',
        'date' => '1512403260',
        'status' => '1',
    ],
];

switch($_REQUEST['function'])
{
    case 'loadTasks':
        $result = [];
        if($_REQUEST['type'] == '' || $_REQUEST['type'] == 'all'){
            echo json_encode($tasks);
            die();
        }
        foreach($tasks as $task){
            if($task['type'] == $_REQUEST['type']){
                $result[] = $task;
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($result);
        break;
    case 'deleteTask':
        if(empty($_REQUEST['id'])){
            echo 0;
            die();
        }
        // code delete task
        echo 1;
        break;
    case 'editTask':
        if(empty($_REQUEST['id']) || empty($_REQUEST['type']) || empty($_REQUEST['name'])){
            echo 0;
            die();
        }
        // code edit task
        echo 1;
        break;
}?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так, php у тебя выводит json-строку.
Ты обращаешься к нему и принимаешь на стороне js с помощью jquery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'func.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(res) {
    // Дальше делай с res-ом, что хочешь. Это будет как раз твоим массивом, который ты выводил в php
  },
});
```

Comment: Понял, в поле url: ссылку на php файл который находится на локальном сервере и  у меня теперь появляется ошибка Failed to load http://test/fnc.php: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Попробуй прописать "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true" в файле .htaccess

Comment: прописал это в самом верху файла, но не помогло

Answer (score 0):

В файле где вызывается функция в самом начале пропишите этот код:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: Ошибка та пропала, но теперь пишет: ReferenceError: header is not defined

Comment: А вы делаете запрос с http на http? или с http на https?

Comment: Тут нужно перед echo дать понять клиенту какой тип данных уйдёт в ответе - в вашем случае это должен быть вызов  header(‘application/json’); а ещё лучше сделать это в самом начале файла по возможности. Да, и это должно быть в PHP файле, а не в JavaScriptовском.

Answer (score 0):

Протоколы должны совпадать) 
а также попробуйте обновить ваш Jquery до последней версии

Comment: Так, в качестве локального сервера я использую openserver где находится этот func.php. В js файле для получения json в url пишу   url: 'http://test/fnc.php' вверху файла этого js файла добавляю то что вы мне выше писали, протокол вроде http но в настройках openserver точной инфы не нашел, jquery обновил. Я понимаю что походу сильно туплю сейчас, за что заранее извиняюсь)